# SwiftからのGETリクエストをPHPで受け取る。PHPからSwiftへの受け渡し。

Tags: swift, php, cakephp

タイトルに書いたように今SwiftからのGETリクエストをcakePHPで受け取る。DB(MySQL)に登録してあるデータをcakePHPからSwiftにデータを送るような流れです。

< Swift >

```
    let url = "送信するURL"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:url)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:{data, response, error in

        print(data)

        if(error == nil){
            let result = NSString(data:data!,encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            //結果を出力(JSON形式)
            print("result=\(result)")
        }else{
            print(error)
        }
```

< PHP >

```
//DB接続
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'imagine');

$table = mysql_select_db('test_db')){
$table = mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8')

//テーブルからデータを取り出す
$table = mysql_query("select id,name,password  from users" , $db)

//レコードごとに配列を取得
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($table)){
//取得した配列を多次元配列にする。
$array[] = array($row);
//json形式でviewに吐く
$this->set(compact('array'));
$this->viewClass = 'Json';
$this->set('_serialize', array('array'));
```

Swift側で結果を出力する（`print("result=\(result)")`）と、

```
{"array":[[{"id":"1","name":"My Name","password":"2015-09-29 06:21"}],[{"id":"2","name":"testuser1","password":"1111"}],[{"id":"3","name":"testuser2","password":"2222"}],[{"id":"4","name":"tomorrow","password":"1234"}],[{"id":"5","name":"tomorrow","password":"1234"}],[{"id":"6","name":"test","password":"1234"}],[{"id":"7","name":" the","password":"1234"}],[{"id":"8","name":" the","password":" 1234"}],[{"id":"9","name":" the","password":" the"}],[{"id":"10","name":" people","password":" the"}],[{"id":"11","name":" the","password":" people"}],[{"id":"12","name":" the","password":" I love the"}]]}
```

のようにJSON形式でSwiftのデバックエリアに表示するところまではできています。
しかし、ここから必要な配列の要素だけを表示することができていません。

SwiftyJSONを使って要素を取得することも試してみました。

```
        do{
            var data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil)
        }catch{
            print("ERROR")
        }
        if data != nil {
            let json = JSON(data: data!)
            print(json)
        }
        if let title = json["array"][0]["id"].string {
            print(title)
        }else{
            print("failed")
        }
```

print(json)の結果、print(title)の結果はどちらもnullになってしまいます。

どなたかお力を貸していただけると幸いです。
説明不足でしたら、随時補足いたします。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 追加情報を踏まえ，回答に追記をしました．ご確認ください．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do{~}`の中で`var`を使い変数を再定義しているため，`do{~}`を抜けた時点で変数dataの内容は元に戻り，その後の`let json = JSON(data: data!)`では空のJSONオブジェクトが生成されてるものと思われます．  
また，`if data != nil {~}`にて変数jsonを`let`にて再定義しているため，正常なJSONオブジェクトが生成されたとしても，`if data != nil {~}`を抜けた時点で元に戻ってしまうのではないかと思います．  
最後に，Jsonデータを見る限り，`json["array"][0]["id"].string`ではアクセスできないので，`json["array"][0][0]["id"].string`とする必要があると思います．

以上を踏まえて修正すると，

```
var data :NSData? = nil;
var json :JSON   = nil;
do{
   data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil)
}catch{
    print("ERROR")
}
if data != nil {
    json = JSON(data: data!)
    print(json)
}
if let title = json["array"][0][0]["id"].string {
    print(title)
}else{
    print("failed")
}
```

となるのかなと思います．

#### 追記

関数全体のコードを見たところ，リクエストを合計2回送ってしまっているようです．
`let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest`でリクエストを一回，   
`jsonData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil)`で一回となっています．

初めのリクエストの結果dataを用いて，以下のように修正してみてはいかがでしょうか？

```
@IBAction func clibkBtn2(sender: UIButton) {
    var json : JSON = nil

    //set url and request
    let url = "http://192.168.33.10/test_app/users/gettest"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:url)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:{data, response, error in

        print(data)

        if data != nil {
            json = JSON(data: data!)
            print(json)
        }

        if let title = json["array"][0][0]["id"].string {
            print(title)
        }else{
            print("failed")
        }
    })
    task.resume()        
}
```

`NSURLConnection`はdeprecated(非推奨)となっているようです．現在は`NSURLSession`が推奨のようです

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
試してみたのですが、print(json)の箇所がnullになってしまいます。

ということはやはりJSON(data:)がうまく機能していないということでしょうか?
プロジェクト内にSwiftyJSON(test_app/test_app/SwiftyJSON.swift)をコピペしてたのですが、その操作だけでは不十分な可能性ということはないでしょうか?

Comment: print(data)は正常に出力されているにもかかわらず，print(json)の出力はnullになっているということですね．SwiftyJSONはSwiftyJSON.swiftとして配置するだけで大丈夫です．もう一度配置し直してみるなど，試してみるのもいいかもしれません．参考までに，こちらの環境で同じjson文字列を返すサーバを立て，実行した様子を貼ります．[スクリーンショット](http://s1.gazo.cc/up/156379.png) (画面右側が出力結果になります)

Answer (score 0):

> mjhd さん

問題解決致したしました。
もう一度SwiftyJSONを再配置したところうまくいきました。ご協力ありがとうございます。

```
    var json : JSON = nil

    //set url and request
    let url = "http://192.168.33.10/test_app/users/gettest"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:url)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:{data, response, error in

        print(data)
        if(error == nil){
            let result = NSString(data:data!,encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            //結果を出力(JSON形式)
            //print(result)
            let json = JSON(data: data!)
            print("json = \(json)")

        }else{
            print(error)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```